# how to install Knockout-jQueryUI?

Tags: knockout.js

```js
<script>
var ViewModel = function () {
this.active = ko.observable(0);
this.selected = ko.computed({
   read: function() { return this.active().toString(); },
   write: function(newValue) { this.active(parseInt(newValue, 10)); },
   owner: this
  });
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="value: selected">
  <option value="0">Panel 1</option>
  <option value="1">Panel 2</option>
  <option value="2">Panel 3</option>
</select>
<div data-bind="accordion: { active: active }">
 <h3>Panel 1</h3>
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <h3>Panel 2</h3>
 <div>consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
 <h3>Panel 3</h3>
 <div>Nunc tincidunt consectetur sagittis</div>
</div>
```

I tried the above code. I am very new to knockout. Please help me out
I want to add accordion and dialogBox .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is you may not be you are getting the file from http instead of https. Just use this:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

The browser will use the page's protocol to try to obtain the file. On non-secure pages, http. On secure pages, https. 
Same for Knockout UI. 
So it will get the script from the correct protocol ...in both http and https contexts.

You may also want to look into if the version of jquery is compatible with the version of knockout ui you are using. I'm not using knockout, but I know this is the case for various UIs out there...